# Python Error When Parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

So I am trying to find the IP address from this JSON:

```
[{"id":"001788fffe48cbdb","internalipaddress":"192.168.1.102"}]
```

So my code to do this is:

```
r_lights = requests.get('https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp')

js= r_lights.json()                                                                     

hue_lights = [js[index]["name"] for index in js]
```

However, it returns the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

I've used that code to successfully search other JSON in my code, but I'm not sure how to change it to work here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
hue_lights = [index["name"] for index in js]
```

or if you want ip's

```
hue_lights = [index["internalipaddress"] for index in js]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string values of the dictionaries directly:

```
for obj in index['name']:
    hue_lights = obj['one']['two']
```